Pandas dataframe select_dtypes not selecting intended datatypes
I am new to pyspark and pandas and I am using pyspark in a databricks environment, in which I am trying to read data from a parquet file, get the columns which are of type 'double' make some modifications to the dataframe and save it in a table,
I came across the command 'select_dtypes' which lets us select a particular type of fiel from a dataframe. Here is how my query looks:
df = spark.read.parquet("s3://location")
pandasdf = df.toPandas()
for column in pandasdf.select_dtypes(include='double'):
         print(f'"{column}"')

and this query returned:
foo,
bar,
foo1,
bar1

Now when I checked dtype before running the for loop like:
 print(df.dtypes)

the command returned the following result,
[('foo', 'double'),('bar','double'),('foo1','int'),('bar1','int')]

MY Question is :

Why are the int fields being considered as double here?
Should I change the query to exclude the int fields?


pandasdf.select_dtypes(include='double', exclude ='int')

did not work as well

What is the rationale for using toPandas in the first place?

I cannot recreate the issue. however in pandas double is not a datatype. Try using float instead

@BigBen to use the select_dtypes function

@iBeMeltin even float is not working

what do you see when you print pandasdf.dtypes?

if I say pandasdf.dtypes the fields foo1 & bar1 are of type 'float64' as well

In pandas, double is not a datatype. You can instead try to use float64 like this:
df.select_dtypes(include=['float64'])


continuing the conversation here if I say  pandasdf.dtypes
the fields foo1 & bar1 are of type 'float64' as well

Something must be happening when you are converting the dataframe that is causing the issue. What is the reason you need pyspark? why not just use pandas from the start?

I am using this in a databricks environment and by default it uses pyspark, I was able to get work around for this by just using the dtypes

for dtype in df.dtypes:
if(dtype[1] == 'double'):
print(dtype[0])
I did not convert the dataframe to pandas and it worked
